# Remote Desktop to home server: From Mac gives english keyboard layout, from PC gives norwegian layout 

Tags: remote-desktop, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to connect to my home server from my Mac, but struggle with typing the password, which contains a plus sign.

I have a Norwegian keyboard layout, and when I log in from Windows (via VMware), I get a Norwegian keyboard at the logon screen, but when I connect directly from the Mac, I get a English keyboard layout, which makes it impossible to type my password...

Why does it give me a different layout for the Mac?

How can I type a plus sign? The key that should give me a plus sign if the keyboard was English, is the key that contains the ´ and `, and using this button doesn't give me anything in the login prompt...

Comment: Does your mac have a numeric keypad, i.e. can you use that to type the plus sign?

Comment: No, it's a macbook without numpad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I soved this problem by storing the password as part of the connection file. That way, I want need to type the password to log in.

Not very secure, but I don't really care about security at this level at home.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying CoRD, it works much better. It's a known problem with Microsoft's RDP. Typical of us Norwegian users! :)

> http://cord.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I tried out CoRD before I got RDP to work. I'm not sure why, but I prefer the original.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use Alt + Shift (when you are logged in) to change the language.
Then you can switch between the installed Windows languages.

Comment: But this has no effect on the login screen, though...